# How to migrate field value within same nid?

Tags: 8, migrations

I need to migrate address field value to paragraph field within same nid. I have migrated address field to paragraph item, but now I need to map that previously migrated paragraph item to paragraph field. Major blocker is that I need to migration of field value within same content. Values in migration_map table is being stored but destination field value is not getting populated.